# Cannot import installed python package

Tags: python

I'm trying to install **python-numpy** package on my ubuntu 14.04 machine. I ran `sudo apt-get install python-numpy` command to install it and it says the package has been installed but when i try to access it, i'm unable to do so.

[image]

Comment: You should ask Ubuntu-specific package installation over at http://askubuntu.com/ (related [numpy tag on askubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/numpy))

Comment: Also, your `sys.path` is pointing to `/usr/local/lib` instead of the typical distribution version of Python which should point to `/usr/lib`.  You might be using a custom compiled Python.  Try using the distribution provided Python if you are using the distribution's Python packages.

Comment: It is likely your `python` symlink points to a Python interpreter that you installed/compiled from source. Do  `readlink -e $(which python)` and let us know what it says.

Answer (score 0):

When you type:

```
sudo pip install package-name
```

It will default install **python2** version of package-name some packages might be supported in both python3 and python3 some might work might not

I would suggest

```
sudo apt-get install python3-pip
sudo pip3 install MODULENAME
```

or can even try this

```
sudo apt-get install curl
curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py | sudo python3
sudo pip3 install MODULENAME
```

Many python packages require also the dev package, so install it too:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-dev
```

Also check for the sys.path [ make sure module is in the python path ]

Comment: Bad advice. There is an official way to do this at the [system level for Ubuntu 14.04](http://askubuntu.com/questions/588438/install-numpy-for-python3-4-0-on-ubuntu-14-04-01-lts).  Your way will muck with the root installation in ways that can break Ubuntu's package management.  Also, `pip` doesn't always reference Python 2's version, though it might be the case for Ubuntu.